# There was an error parsing 'Gemfile': An empty gem name is not valid

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I have a student receiving an error when running 'bundle install'. Things look right as far as file structure and the gemspec file. However I can't quite understand what this error is wanting to tell me. There are a lot of posts out there about this error, however they pertain to specific gems like 'bcrypt' etc. I don't see much out there regarding gemspec.

```
[!] There was an error parsing 'Gemfile': An empty gem name is not valid. Bundler cannot continue. 
#   from /users/Kris/Desktop/Ruby-CLI-project/ruby_cli_project/Gemfile:7
#   --------------------------------------------
#
>   gamspec
#
#   --------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the Gemfile to allow us to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is intended in Gemfile, the syntax should look like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
gem 'other-gem-name'
```

If you want to package your ruby as a gem, then create `.gemspec` file not `Gemfile`. `gemspec` doesn't need to be inserted inside Gemfile.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to make sure that was okay. I had her comment out the gemspec when she needed to run bundle install. I wasn't sure if the gemspec was necessary or not.